# Taking A URL Query & Setting it to javascript val an POST Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some javascript to pick up a currency query in the URL and then use the existing Ajax post method from the website to load up the correct currency depending on what URL was linked to.

```
my-url.com/?currency=USD <- loads the site in US Dollars 
my-url.com/?currency=GBP <- loads the site in British Pounds 
my-url.com/?currency=EUR <- loads the site in EUROS
```

This is the stock code for the currency selector to change the currency on the website:

```
$('#currency').on 'change', ->
    $.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: $(this).data('href')
      data:
        currency: $(this).val()
).done ->
window.location.reload()
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?currency=EUR") >= 0) {

    $.ajax(
        type: 'POST'
        url: $(this).data('href')
        data:
        currency: $(this).val()
    ).done 

}
```

It does not work as I am not pulling in the currency into the post method, and probably other reasons too.

This is beyond my scope, would anyone know how I would go about setting the JS to check on load for a currency in the url, set that to the currency value in the script and POST?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? You sound like your out of your depth and are just hoping for someone to do (something?) for you. This isn't a free code writing service. You're expected to ask answerable questions?

Comment: So what is the problem? `$(this)` is going to be `window`, I highly doubt you have data on the window object,

Comment: Reading it again, is this what you want? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, how do I get the currency query into a variable, considering that the currency might not always be the last part of the url, or may have further queries like location.

Comment: right, so this is a duplicate then?

Comment: Ive taken the stock currency selector script and went to mould that into some script that checks fo r a url query and sets the correct currency on load. I guess my first real question is.. Is it possible to set query parameters to a variable in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

If the currency is three characters long and its the last query at the end of url, you can try this:

```
window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.length-3)
```

It takes the href value and removes everything else but the last three characters at the end.

Comment: Thanks, That helps somewhat, I think my first step is having the url checked for currency in a query and then taking that and setting it as a variable. Your method works if the currency query is the last part of the url. Is there a more sure fire way of setting a js variable to the content of a url query.